# WCAG 2.0 Support In ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: accessibility, asp.net-4.0

Have there been any improvements to aid accessibility standard compliance in ASP.NET 4.0?

(WCAG 2.0 in particular)

Comment: Do you have a particular accessibility standard in mind?

Comment: There is a detailed description from MS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228004.aspx

Comment: @Bobo, Don't think that article contains whether there's been improvements though, does it? I haven't read it in a while though.